# Is it accepted to write in a span without h1 inside?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

is it conventional to write inside a span? without a h1 inside?
and then with media-queries change the font-size of span to a small?

thanks

e.g

```
<span class="ab">Tip number 1 ....</span>
<span class="ab">Tip number 2 ....</span>
<span class="ab">Tip number 3 ....</span>

@media (min-width:720px){

.ab {
font-size:1.5em;

}

}
```

Comment: Its completely upto you. Are you getting any error with the above written code?

Comment: Why would it not be acceptable?

Comment: First of all, `h1’ inside `span` is _not_ acceptable (it’s not allowed by the HTML specification). The opposite is completely OK. Styling `span`s like heading isn’t bad itself, but usually it’s better to use proper elements in HTML (h1-h6 for headings, ul and ol for lists, tables for tabular data etc.) and not mimic them with other elements and styles.